# Jquery hide of anchor tag

Tags: jquery, html

how to hide the supremeLabel

var _sidebar = "";
_sidebar = " " + "" + "Narrow By COURT" + "" + " Supreme Court (" + supreme_court_case + ") ";
";

$("#sidehide").append(_sidebar);

Comment: why this you are needed? it is already with you before append so use that.

Comment: `$( _sidebar ).prop( 'id' )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the string into a jQuery object so you can access to its attributes.

```
var _sidebar = $("<div class='col-lg-2' id='sidebar1'> " + 
               "<a href='#' class='list-group-item active'>" + 
               "Narrow By COURT" + "</a>" + 
               "<a href='#' class='list-group-item' id='supremeLabel'> Supreme Court (" + supreme_court_case + ")</a></div>");

alert(_sidebar.prop('id')); // returns "sidebar1"
```

You can also access to its children properties:

```
alert(_sidebar.children('a').last().prop('id')); // returns "supremeLabel"
```

Comment: var supreme_court_case = 0;                  if(supreme_court_case ==0) { i want to hide the anchor tag of  the id of supremeLabel}

Comment: Then type `if( supreme_court_case === 0 ) _sidebar.find('#supremeLabel1').hide()`

Comment: the code hides all the div.........and i want it to hide the particular anchor tag

Comment: Please update your question with your current code and, if it is possible, set up a jsfiddle to ease the understanding of the problem. If you need an answer for a different question please post a new question. At this time is hard to know what are you trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
var tobeappendedElId = $(_sidebar).attr('id');
```

or for the link:

```
var tobeappendedElId = $(_sidebar).find('a').eq(2).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `attr()` jQuery property,

```
$(YOUR_IDENTIFIER).attr(id);
```